# Is there a way to specify the initial cursor position in a Visual Studio item template?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-templates

When you add, for example, a class to a project by selecting Add > New Item > Visual C# Items > Class, the blinking text cursor inside the new class will be at row 1, column 1. Is there a way to modify the template so that the blinking cursor appears in a different location?

```
using System;

namespace SomeNamespace
{
    class SomeClass
    {
        | <--- I'd like the blinking cursor to initially appear here
    }
}
```

Comment: have you found any solution that works?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You want to use $END$. You can also make fields by surrounding other keywords with $$.

```
using System;

namespace $Namespace$
{
    public class $ClassName$
    {
        $END$
    }
}
```

Comment: I just realized this doesn't appear to work if ReSharper is not installed.

Comment: Resharper only. See: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Templates__Template_Basics__Template_Variables.html. There doesn't appear to be any way to do this in vanilla VS.